# Webtc, connect user to the same offer but different answer?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have simple webrtc video chat that can support only two users (by extending this serverless implementation https://github.com/cjb/serverless-webrtc/) 
I am building connection like this: first user opens a page and clicks create button, the offer gets saved to a file on server, and creator starts sending repeated ajax requests to check for an answer.

User 2 connects to  page and clicks join, he gets the offer from server via ajax, generate an answer and saves it to a file via ajax.

User 1 can now pick up the answer from user 2 via his ajax and they are successfully connected.

The problem is when user 2 refreshes the page and tries to connect again. User one detects iceConnectionState === 'disconnected' and starts checking for answer again... After user 2 generates the answer nothing happens. I can see that he is creating the answer and that user 1 is accepting it but peer.onopen never gets fired again, and i cant connect users.

Is there anything that i should do before trying to reconnect them? Clear the stream somehow, clear connection, reinitialise something etc

Comment: What I do(which may not be the most efficient way but works the most consistently for my me) is that I re-construct the peerconnection when a session fails(i.e. when a peer leaves). This in tails creating a complete new peerconnection with your options, creating the offer again, sending it to the peer when they are available, and handling the answer again.

Comment: Thanks, i will take this in consideration...
PS i found out that you can't use same SDP (same offer) to reconnect the peer that refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not serverless. Its just client-server signalling based on polling.

Sounds like the RTCPeerConnection at user 1 is closing on page refresh. You need to re-create an RTCPeerConnection and then createOffer in order to set the local description on it. I don't know if it would work if you call setLocalDescription using the previously generated offer (the one before the page refresh) and then try to accept the answer?